# Probability problem - Big deviations and Hoeffding's inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Say I have a box with green and red balls, $N$ in total.

I know the probability $\mu$ of picking a red one. If I want the probability by which in picking $n$ balls on $N$ at least $k$ are red I have to use Bernoulli statistics, and here it is ok.

But if I want the MINIMUM number of extractions $n$ in order to have a fixed probability (that I fix, for example $0.9$) of picking at least $k$ balls of a fixed colour, the shall I use bid deviations?

I thought about Vapnick - Chervonekis law and Hoeffding's inequality (that is for discrete Bernoullian processes) but it requires me to fix a parameter  $\epsilon$ which I don't know how to fix and choose.

Any help for that?

The idea is that the probability by which the real mean of the red balls differs from a certain $\epsilon$ (which I take as a threshold tolerance) is bounded by the right term of the inequality:

$$P(|\nu - \mu| < \epsilon) \leq 2e^{-2\epsilon^2 n}$$

where $n$ is the number of balls I pick, considering it can be whatever (and the mean is unknown).

It's like to put a constraint on the error of the $n$ extractions so that I can state the mean is the one I calculate through the $n$ extractions.

(Anyway: the problem is this. Of the $N$ total balls, $1/4$ are green. I want to extract $n$ balls such that I am sure that at least 2 of them are green.)

Comment: *How* sure do you want to be?

Comment: @PhoemueX I want a probability of $0.9$